# Changing resolution on touchscreen

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, xrandr, xinput

My screen resolution is supposed to be 1366x768 according to the screen documentation. In viewing the display, it goes "off the screen" so I am guessing the resolution is simply set incorrectly. Here is what I have done so far:

Check if evdev is installed:

`dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-input`

Install evdev driver:

`apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev`

Check if evdev driver is installed

`dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-input`

Check if configuration files are in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d directory.

`cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
ls`

Install xinput-calibrator

`sudo apt-get install xinput-calibrator`

**After installation**

At this stage `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` contains:

`10-evdev.conf 10-quirks.conf 70-synaptics.conf 70-wacom.conf`

At this stage I assume that `10-evdev.conf` is the one I need to use since that is the driver I just installed

So lastly I run:
`DISPLAY=:0.0 xinput_calibrator --output-type xinput`
which runs and states width = 1200, height = 800 but the screen is still at an "oversized resolution"

**What else I have tried**

From reading other people's questions, I have tried the following:

Listing `xrandr` shows:

```
default connected 1200x800*0*0 0mm x 0mm
1280x800     0.00*
```

and nothing more so I try to add a resolution:

`xrandr --addmode default "1366X768_60.00"` and
`xrandr --addmode default "1366x768_60.00"`
but both result in `cannot find mode "1366X768_60.00"`

Therefore.. I try to add a new resolution:
`xrandr --newmode "1366x768_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync`

Then typing `xrandr` I get the same as below with my new resolution added. I do note that the star (*) is still on the 1280x800 one and not my new resolution so I try:

`xrandr --addmode default "1366x768_60.00"`
which seems to take but the star never moves and the resolution doesn't change either..

I try:
`xrandr --output default --mode 1366x768_60.00`
but it states `Failed to get size of gamma for output default. Configure crtc 0 failed`